# How to change the sequence of the numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, task

Hello I have again question. I build js where you can add numbers in the following order 
-> 50-20 and in the select you got the numbers started from 20,21,22,23,24,25... til 50 . I want to change the order of the code when you put 50-20 the result in the select should start with 50 and counting from 50,49,48,.... til 20 .

Here is my code on a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qpWLf/). The question might be very stupid but now i'm so confused :X .

```
HTML


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alertify.core.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alertify.default.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text /css'>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Enter values</h1>

        <p class="example">number - number</p>

        <input type="text" name="field" id="keys" class="button"/>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="calculate" class="press">Push!</a>

        <div id="select_result">
            <!-- Generate Dynamic Select! -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- End wrapper div -->

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/task.js"></script>
    <script src="js/alertify.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>








JS


     $(document).ready(function () {

            function calculateResult(){

                var value_1 = parseInt( $("#keys").val().split("-")[0] );
                var value_2 = parseInt( $("#keys").val().split("-")[1] );

                if( $("#keys").val().indexOf("-") == "-1" ){
                    // alert dialog
                    alertify.alert("Въведи две цифри с тире!");

                    return;
                } else if ( typeof value_1 == 'undefined' || typeof value_2 == 'undefined' || value_1 == "" || value_2 == "" || isNaN(value_1) || isNaN(value_2)) {
                    // error notification
                    // shorthand for alertify.log("Notification", "error");
                    alertify.error("Въведи две цифри!");

                    return;

                }


                var select_string = "";
                select_string = "<select>";
                if ( value_1 > value_2 ){
                    for( i = value_2; i <= value_1; i++ ){
                        select_string += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
                    }

                } else if ( value_1 < value_2 ){
                    for( i = value_1; i >= value_2; i++ ){
                        select_string += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
                    }
                } else if ( value_1 == value_2 ){
                    select_string += "<option>" + value_1 + "</option>";
                }
                select_string += "</select>";

                $("#select_result").html(select_string);

            }


            $("#calculate").on("click", function(){
                calculateResult();

            });
            $(document).on("keypress", function (e) {
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    calculateResult(e);

                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Add [relevant] code to your question. Don't just link to fiddle. That's why SO gives you a warning if you try to include a link without code! Also, it's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Is this really harder than just subtracting 1 in a loop instead of adding 1?

Comment: I added the qualifier "relevant" for a reason. Don't just dump code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for( i = value_1; i >= value_2; i-- ){
      select_string += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
      console.log(select_string);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qpWLf/4/)**